# Google Maps in Zurb Foundation not Re-centering on Toggle

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation

I'm working on integrating Google Maps into an accordian tab in a template using Zurb Foundation (I believe it's an older version 4?).

You can see the page here: http://terrapatio.com.s150174.gridserver.com/wp/locations/

What I know is that the map will now render when I toggle the "Map" accordian link, it seems to have issues when dealing with multiple maps. The final map in the bottom row, far right is centered correctly, but the rest are not.

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` doesn't seem to be triggered on click for the other maps. I've looked at other questions related to this and tried to follow their suggestions, but I still haven't figured out a good solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

And my code is below:

```
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 10,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// create map               
map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];

// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});

// center map
center_map( map );

 }

 /*
 *  add_marker
  *
 *  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
 *
 *  @type   function
 *  @date   8/11/2013
  *  @since 4.3.0
 *
 *  @param  $marker (jQuery element)
 *  @param  map (Google Map object)
 *  @return n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{
    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html()
    });

    // show info window when marker is clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.open( map, marker );

    });
}

}


function center_map( map ) {

// vars
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// loop through all markers and create bounds
$.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

});

// only 1 marker?
if( map.markers.length == 1 )
{
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
}
else
{
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

}

/*
 *  document ready
 *
 *  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
 *
 *  @type   function
 *  @date   8/11/2013
  *  @since 5.0.0
 *
 *  @param  n/a
 *  @return n/a
 */

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function() {
        render_map( $(this) );
     });


     $('.map-link').click(function (e) {
        resetMap(map);
     });


    function resetMap(m){
        x = m.getZoom();
        c = m.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'resize');
        m.setZoom(x);
        m.setCenter(c);
    };
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly by not using the `var` keyword when you create your maps, you're making the map variable global, not local to your render_map function:

```
map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
```

This means that you can reference it without error on your click event handler:

```
$('.map-link').click(function (e) {
    resetMap(map);
});
```

So on page load you've called the `render_map` function multiple times for each of your `.acf-map` elements.  The `map` variable gets created on the first iteration of that function.  Thereafter it gets **updated** for each other iteration.

So at the end of that loop over the `.acf-map` elements, `map` will be the object of the last map.

So this simply associates your last map object with the click handler for every `.map-link` link.

```
 $('.map-link').click(function (e) {
    resetMap(map);
 });
```

Make sense?  I would move that link click event handler **inside** your `render_map` function, and make `map` a local variable to that function.

Comment: Thank you duncan. I tried your suggestion by moving both the click event handler aand `resetMap` function inside the `render_map` function. Not sure if I'm did it correctly, but now it renders the first map that's toggled correctly, but subsequent maps are incorrectly centered and no markers are placed.

Comment: Duncan, thank you for your persistence in following up on this. After talking to the designer, I think that rather than showing multiple maps, a more simple, and elegant solution is to just show a single map with multiple markers. So at this point, we're going to no longer pursue this.